# xtext and junit pde

Tags: eclipse, junit, eclipse-plugin, xtext, eclipse-pde

I'm doing some unit tests of my xtext applications using junit pde. The class that I want to test uses an injected IResourceSetProvider but when I call my class from my test class, the ResourceSet Provider is null. I guess I have to inject it somehow.

Also, I have to mention that I'm working with 2 plugin projects. One with my xtext applications and the other one with my test cases.

How can I invoke my xtext class from the test case and have the ResourceSet Provider injected?

Answer (score 1):

You should your test file using the XtextRunner class, and using the InjectWith annotation you could provide the necessary input. E.g. see

```
@RunWith(XtextRunner.class)
@InjectWith(XXXLanguageInjectorProvider.class)
public class ParserTest {
```

Where XXXLanguageInjectorProvider is a class generated by Xtext in the default test project.